# communication between main thread and worker thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a problem.
I have a main class `RunAnimation`, and class `Animation` extends `Runnable`.
In code main function of `RunAnimation`:

```
Thread animation = new Thread(new Animation("cat" ));
animation.start();
```

In code run function of `Animation`:

```
run() {
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //SEND ALERT TO MAIN THREAD
    }
}
```

My question are: how to I can alert for main thread after 1000ms.

Thank all.

Comment: There are many different ways, Google is a good start - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Java+inter+thread+communication
Think about what exactly you want to do, send message/data, wake main thread, do something else...

Comment: Why do you want to communicate? Let the `Animation` perform the desired action.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when saying "send alet to main thread" ? what do you want to do ?

You can use a shared variable for example, if you want your two threads to communicate

Comment: I want send a message to main thread. Example  after 1000ms main thread write : - Cat run 1 second .... Cat run n second...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you have to be more explicit. What do you intend to do exactly?

Have you tryed to create a method the executes right after it leaves the sleep() that informs the main method?

```java
run() {
    while(true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        animation.warn();
        //Rest of the loop.
    }
}
```